# what are pushed onto the stack and later restored during a function call and an interrupt service routine

Tags: function, stack

I know probably this is a very simple and common stuff for a programmer but I just want to know the complete answer.Suppose the OS is Linux.

What I know is the current program counter(the returning address) and some general purpose registers(because it might be used by the new function or ISR). What else?

Comment: Function parameters. Sometimes. Depends on the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Comment: @JimMischel Hi Jim. Thanks. I forgot this. What else do you know?

Comment: The calling convention article and the links therein will probably answer your questions. What gets saved depends not only on the OS, but also on the language being used and the hardware platform.

Comment: One more: in some OO language implementations (for example, some C++ compilers), the `this` pointer is pushed onto the stack when calling member functions, but when calling static functions there is no `this` pointer pushed. The question you asked is very broad and probably can't be answered outside the context of a specific OS on a specific hardware platform with a specific memory model. I'm voting to close the question as too broad.